# Strange setRowspan error/not working

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I set up a header for my iText-table which has 6 columns, later I wanted to use the very same header for another table and set the colspans more generic, but the one rowspan then doesn't work any more.

This is my original (working) code with the 6 columns:

```
public static PdfPTable createHeaderContent() {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);

    PdfPCell dobicell = new PdfPCell();
    dobicell.setColspan(2);
    dobicell.addElement(new Phrase(docType, DOBIFONTADR));
    dobicell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.TOP);
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    dobicell = new PdfPCell();
    dobicell.setColspan(2);
    dobicell.addElement(new Phrase("Ing. Mario J. Schwaiger", DOBIFONTADR));
    dobicell.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    dobicell = Dobilogo.getPiccell(92, 104);
    dobicell.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP | Rectangle.RIGHT);
    dobicell.setColspan(3);
    dobicell.setRowspan(2);
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    dobicell = getKundenCol(kunde);
    dobicell.setColspan(2);
    dobicell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    dobicell = getUserCell(user);
    dobicell.setColspan(2);
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    return table;
}
```

The result looks like it should (I've used some nice colouring to indicate the spans:
[image]

The modified code for the "general purpose" is pretty much the same:

```
public static PdfPTable createHeaderContent(int[] coldist) {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(coldist[0] + coldist[1] + coldist[2]); //createHeaderContent(new int[]{4, 7, 4, 4, 7});
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);

    PdfPCell dobicell = new PdfPCell();
    dobicell.setColspan(coldist[0]); //used to be 2, now 4
    dobicell.addElement(new Phrase(doctype, DOBIFONTADR));        
    dobicell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.TOP);
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    dobicell = new PdfPCell();
    dobicell.setColspan(coldist[1]); //used to be 2, now 7
    dobicell.addElement(new Phrase("Ing. Mario J. Schwaiger", DOBIFONTTITEL));
    dobicell.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    dobicell = Dobilogo.getPiccell(92, 104);
    dobicell.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP | Rectangle.RIGHT);
    dobicell.setColspan(coldist[2]); //used to be 3, now 4
    dobicell.setRowspan(2);  // <--- This is fishy, but why?
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    dobicell = getKundenCol(kunde);
    dobicell.setColspan(coldist[3]); //used to be 2, now 4
    dobicell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    dobicell = getUserCell(user);
    dobicell.setColspan(coldist[4]); //used to be 2, now 7
    table.addCell(dobicell);

    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    return table;
}
```

But there is something wrong with the last column:
[image]

At first I assumed there's another row hidden and used `dobicell.setRowspan(3);` but this alters the first data-row already. Trying to add another cell puts it in the first row after the header.

Strangely when I widen the user-cell in the last part to the whole rowspaned cell disappears.

Is there a solution or reason for this issue?

Comment: Your *"original (working) code with the 6 columns"* looks weird because it strictly speaking requires 7 columns: You have twice `setColspan(2)` and once `setColspan(3)`, so summed up you have 7 columns. Furthermore, you have `setHeaderRows(1)` - how do you expect that to work in combination with a `setRowspan(2)` in that single header row? You have removed the first problem in your *"modified code"* but kept the second one. It appears as if both problems combined by chance happen to cancel each other out but the second problem alone results in your observation.

Comment: I have just checked the whole code and it's weird: Yes, you are absolutely right, i had a `setColspan(3)` in there. But putting it back to `setColspan(2)` had no effect. As I was writing this question I did some testing, maybe it slipped through and remained. Related to the `setHeaderRows(1)` - you noticed that as well. No, it's the original code. While I was programming on that part I first copied some working code from available online sources and forgot to adjust it... as it worked. `setHeaderRows(2)` did nothing. Apparently due to the rowspan, but that's just a guess.

Comment: You were right. In the modified version I still had `setHeaderRows(1)`. Replacing it with `setHeaderRows(2)` solved the issue

Comment: Ok, I'll make my comment an actual answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here, one which iText seems to ignore and one which causes the problem:

- In the original code the cells require 7 columns as they have twice `setColspan(2)` and once `setColspan(3)` in a row. But the table is only constructed for 6 columns: `new PdfPTable(6)`.

  iText seems to ignore the missing column here...
- The code declares the first row to be a header for the table: `table.setHeaderRows(1)`. This clashes with the declaration of the last cell in the first row to span 2 rows `setRowspan(2)`.

  iText here ignores the rowspan in the header row resulting in the undesired appearance.

  To fix this, don't declare a row span at all or use a row span of at least two (if enough rows are going to follow).

In a comment the OP confirmed

> In the modified version I still had `setHeaderRows(1)`. Replacing it with `setHeaderRows(2)` solved the issue